# Memorylessness of coin flips

Tags: random-variables, expectation

Let $Z \sim\text{Geometric}(0.5)$. Let's say we're using $Z$ to model the number of times we need to flip a fair coin (independently of previous flips) to get heads. Let's say we know that the first coin flip is tails, and we are now interested in the number of flips *after* the first until getting heads. Let's call $Y$ the number of flips after the first until getting heads.

Clearly, for a given value of $Z$, the value of $Y$ will be one less (since it doesn't include the first flip). Then it seems to make sense that $Y = Z - 1\Rightarrow \mathbb{E}[Y]=\mathbb{E}[Z-1]=\mathbb{E}[Z]-1=2-1=1$.

On the other hand, the memoryless property of the geometric distribution seems to suggest that we have $Y \sim\text{Geometric}(0.5)$, which implies $\mathbb{E}[Y]=2$.

Why do these two lines of reasoning disagree, and which is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have: $$Z=1-T+T(1+Y)=1+TY$$ where $T$ corresponds with tails at the first flip.

This with $T\sim\mathsf{Bernoulli}(0.5)$ and $Y\sim \mathsf{Geometric}(0.5)$ where $T$ and $Y$ are independent.

Then: $$\mathsf EZ=\mathsf E(1+TY)=1+\mathsf ET\mathsf EY=1+0.5\cdot2=2$$

Next to that we have:$$\mathsf E [Z\mid T=1]=\mathsf E (1+Y)=1+\mathsf EY=1+2=3$$

You came up with $\mathsf EY=\mathsf EZ-1$. This is wrong and should have been $\mathsf EY=\mathsf E [Z\mid T=1]-1$.